# Where does C function execution stop

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, execution

In the project folder I have:

```
libtest.so
test.h
```

I have imported `ctypes` in my python code (not sure if it was necessary) and I loaded .so file like following:

```
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libtest.so')
```

In "test.h" C header file I have:

```
long TEST_API test( 
                        ___OUT_ char text[41],
                        ___OUT_ char* pcReceiptSignature,

                        );
```

I call "`test`" from python code like following:

```
class StructA(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("text", c_char*41),
                 ("pcReceiptSignature",c_char*1),
                ]



sampleStruct = StructA("","")

def test2():

    res = lib.test(sampleStruct.text,                               sampleStruct.pcReceiptSignature)
return res
```

but execution fails somewhere and I never get to "`return res`" line.

For the lengths specified for c_chars defined in the structured I also tried giving them no lengths (no change).

What am I doing wrong here. Is there anyway to see where the execution fails?

Comment: You can not pass arrays as parameters in C, those are mere pointers in disguise. Also, reduce the code before posting it here.

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt. I reduced the repetitive similar sections.

Comment: Sorry I guess you need to give yet simpler failing example with C source code, cannot find anything wrong there yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should run the code under debugger, compiling the `.so` with `-g` etc.

But one obvious error in your original code would be that `char* pcReceiptSignature` is declared an **out** parameter? thus I guess you want to reserve some space for it, to be filled by the function, but none is available (you are using `c_char_p` instead of an array!). The `pcRpcReceiptSignature` is a pointer to the constant string `""` and thus overwriting it would not be very safe.

Comment: Thanks @Antti . I only have the .so file, I don't have the source code to run the code under debugger. I have changed "c_char_p" to ("pcReceiptSignature",c_char*1) But I still have the same problem. Any idea? I have edited my question based on your comment.

Comment: In that case, there is not much more we can do to help.

Comment: Thanks @Antti for finding the issue in my code! I have defined out_char = ctypes.c_char() and then I passed ctypes.byref(out_char) to test function and everything works fine.